# MongoDB Query Syntax: how to use $isNull inside $in (pymongo api)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document that looks like:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId(),
"employees": [
   {
        "_id": ObjectId(),
        "sharedBranches": [
            ObjectId(),
            ObjectId()
        ]
   },
{
        "_id": ObjectId()
   }
]
}
```

I am trying to return the documents that contains my input ObjectId in the `sharedBranches` field, and also filter the `employees` array down so it only contains objects whose `sharedBranches` contains my input ObjectId.

However, not every `employee` object (i.e. the elem in the `employees` array) contains the `sharedBranches` field. My query is returning an error which I am pretty sure is due to the Nulls, but I can't figure out the syntax for `$isNull`. here is my query. (note the branch_id is the input ObjectId I am searching on.

```
collection = client["collection"]["documents"]
pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "employees.sharedBranches": {"$elemMatch": {"$eq": ObjectId(branch_id)}},
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "employees": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$employees",
                        "as": "employees",
                        "cond": {"$in": [ObjectId(branch_id), {"$ifNull": ["$$employees.sharedBranches", []]}]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

This query returns the error:

```
OperationFailure: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: object, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'code': 40081, 'errmsg': '$in requires an array as a second argument, found: object', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1639079887, 1)}
```

It seems that the `$ifNull` stuff is not evaluating to an array. If I remove the `$ifNull` stuff, and just try to use `$in` on the array directly (so my `$cond` looks like:
`"cond": {"$in": [ObjectId(branch_id), "$$employees.sharedBranches"]}`,

I get this error:

```
OperationFailure: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: string, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'code': 40081, 'errmsg': '$in requires an array as a second argument, found: string', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1639080588, 1)}
```

So I am at a loss of how to resolve this. Is my issue with the `$ifNull`? Am I mistaken that it's needed at all?

Comment: `found: object` - I'm pretty sure null is not an object.  Have you tried checking for array with `$type`?

Comment: Weird.  I duped your input data and created the same pipeline and it worked.  The `$ifNull` expr properly turned the blank (missing) array into `[]` and the `$filter` worked fine.

Comment: Here's what I think happened:   The thing that built the `sharedBranches` array created a single string val instead of an array of one.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect some of your `sharedBranches` fields are not arrays but strings with a single ID.  Here is a little trick that sniffs for the `$type` of such things and if the field is not an array (which includes if it is missing which will return `missing`), it turns it into an array of one:

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {
    employees: {$filter: {
            input: "$employees",
            as: "employees",
            cond: {$in: [targetSharedBranchID, {$cond:
                        {if:{$ne:[{$type:'$$employees.sharedBranches'},"array"]},
                         then:  ['$$employees.sharedBranches'], // ah HA!  Create array of one on the fly.
                                                                // OK if missing; will create an empty array.
                         else: '$$employees.sharedBranches'
                        }} ] }
        }}
    }}

    ,{$match: {$expr: {$gt:[{$size:"$employees"},0]} }}

]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Buzz. i like this approach, and I am not familiar with mongo queries enough to figure that out for myself. Only issue, it doesn't work. i am still getting the "second element must be array" error. I played around with your code and tried replacing the then and else to return empty arrays (like this- then: [], else: []). When I do this, I am still getting the "second element must be array error". So it's leading me to believe it's not a data thing, but a query thing. Could there be a difference between the python api and the raw mongo api?

Comment: @Alan I just converted my javascript to python and reran it and it worked -- but of course this is with my data.   I have `employee` arrays with `sharedBranches` as arrays, strings, and missing entirely.  There's something going on in your data set that is not being handled by the if/then/else.  Try: `db.foo.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$employees"}
    ,{"$match": {"$expr": {"$and":[
        {"$ne":[{"$type":"$employees.sharedBranches"},"array"]},
 {"$ne":[{"$type":"$employees.sharedBranches"},"missing"]}
        ]}
                 }}
])` to discover what is going on.